# Django return json and context data

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, django

I have a form that its processed with ajax and I need to get a return from the view, since I make some validations. The call to the view works fine but if I try to get a response from the view to the javascript (json) I loose the context data.

This is my ajax call that works just fine ( returns 202 OK ), but if data.valid == false, the message is shown but without the context data in the template.

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
      url: '/validate_create/',
     contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8',
     csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
     data: frmData,
     dataType: "json",
     success: function(data)
      {
          if (data.valid== true){

            alert ('validation ok');
          }else{
            alert ('validation error');

          }
        },
     error: function (data) {
         alert('err');
    }

   });
```

This is my original return from the view ( without returning any data ):

```
return render_to_response('shop/checkout.html', ctx, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

And after checking other posts I did this but doesnt return the context (cart in this case in session)

```
context = {}
context['data'] = render_to_string("shop/checkout.html", {'cart':    cart,'valid':valid})
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(context), content_type = "application/json")
```

**UPDATE: the code above was ok, and the ajax received the response with the json.** I had something wrong with the view causing the session to be deleted.

By the way, in the ajax call data.valid works fine in the condition but if I console.log is undefined.

Comment: Have you inspected the response from the server, what's in there?

Comment: the response from the server is ok, I have solved this issue, it had to do with a wrong validation in the view causing the session to be deleted.